# ACF Background Images

Tags: javascript, wordpress, image, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I have a wordpress website that fetches data from ACF. The website's homepage has 6 posts with background images that stretches to height of the screen. 
I want to add another post/section into website's home page. But when I do that all the images disappear from background.
Can anyone help me with this?
These are my codes;

```
function bannerLoad(){
     var getHeight = $(window).height();
    $(".home-banner").css('height', getHeight);

    $('.home-banner').each(function(){
        var homebannerid = $(this).attr('id');
        var imgsrc = $(this).find('img.slide-img').attr('src');
        $("#"+homebannerid).backstretch(imgsrc, {speed: 300});
    });
```

Homepage

```
            <?php
            /*
            Template Name: Homepage Template
            */

            get_header(); ?>
            <?php
            $args = array('post_type' => 'home_post','order' => 'ASC','posts_per_page' => -1); 
            $custom_posts = get_posts($args);
            $i=0;
            foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
                $title = get_the_title();
                $title = str_replace(" ","",$title);
                $banner_image = get_field('banner_image'); 
                $link_target = get_field('select_pagelink_target');
            ?>
            <div class="pagename" id="home-page"></div>
            <div id="banner-slide<?php echo $i; //strtolower($title);?>" class="home-banner">
                <div class="banner-caption-wrap">
                    <div class="banner-caption">
                        <h3><?php echo get_the_title();?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo worthy_limited_excerpt(get_the_ID(),'30'); //the_content();?></p>
                        <?php
                            if($link_target == '') {
                                $target = '';
                            }else{
                                $target = 'target="_'.$link_target.'"';
                            }
                        ?>  
                        <a  <?php echo $target ?> href="<?php echo $page_link = get_field('page_link');?>"><?php echo $link_title = get_field('link_title'); ?></a>
                        <!-- LINK TEXT -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php //home_post_images
                //echo $banner_image;
                 if( $banner_image ){ ?>
                    <img  src="<?php echo $banner_image; ?>" alt="" class="slide-img" />
                <?php }     
              ?>
</div>
<?php 
$i++;
endforeach;?>
<div class="next_btn_wrap">
    <a href="#" class="next_btn"><?php _e( 'Next', 'alainclub' ); ?></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    bannerLoad();

</script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

CSS snippet for homepage:

```
                /* Home Banner 
                ------------------------------------------------*/
                .slide-img{display: none;}
                .backstretch{background: #1d082b;}
                .home-banner{background: #1d082b; height: 1024px;}
                /* Banner Caption */
                .banner-caption-wrap { margin: 0 auto;  max-width: 1200px;  width: 100%; position: relative;}
                .home-banner .banner-caption
                {color: #fff; position: absolute; width:585px; left:0; padding:40px; top:124px;
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.85) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); 
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.85)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0)));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.85) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.85) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); 
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.85) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.85) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 );
                }
                .home-banner .banner-caption p { color:#fff; font-weight:normal; font-size:15px; line-height:24px; margin-bottom:0; height: 75px;}
                .home-banner .banner-caption a { background:rgba(90, 38, 124, 0.86) none repeat scroll 0 0; text-decoration:none; font-size:24px; padding:15px 40px; color:#fff; border:2px solid #fff; display:inline-block; margin-top:35px; text-transform:uppercase;}
                .home-banner .banner-caption h3 { margin-top:20px; background:url(../images/brand-icon.png) no-repeat 0 top ; color:#fff; font-size:45px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:50px; text-transform:uppercase; margin-bottom:20px;}

                #banner-slide2 .banner-caption h3 span { font-size:47px; color:#fff;}
                /* Banner Mouse Btn */
                .next_btn_wrap { position:fixed; width:100%; text-align:center; left:0; bottom:0;}
                .next_btn_wrap a.next_btn { display:inline-block; width:16px; height:25px; overflow:hidden; text-indent:-50px; background:url(../images/click_mouse.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy Past this code and try 
**UPDATED**

```
     <?php
    /*
    Template Name: Homepage Template
    */
 get_header(); ?>
            <?php
            $args = array('post_type' => 'home_post','order' => 'ASC','posts_per_page' => -1); 
            $custom_posts = get_posts($args);
            $i=0;
            foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
                $title = get_the_title();
                $title = str_replace(" ","",$title);
                $banner_image = get_field('banner_image',get_the_ID()); 
                $link_target = get_field('select_pagelink_target',get_the_ID());
            ?>
            <div class="pagename" id="home-page"></div>
            <div id="banner-slide<?php echo $i; //strtolower($title);?>" class="home-banner">
                <div class="banner-caption-wrap">
                    <div class="banner-caption">
                        <h3><?php echo get_the_title();?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo worthy_limited_excerpt(get_the_ID(),'30'); //the_content();?></p>
                        <?php
                            if($link_target == '') {
                                $target = '';
                            }else{
                                $target = 'target="_'.$link_target.'"';
                            }
                        ?>  
                        <a  <?php echo $target ?> href="<?php echo $page_link = get_field('page_link');?>"><?php echo $link_title = get_field('link_title'); ?></a>
                        <!-- LINK TEXT -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php //home_post_images
                //echo $banner_image;
                 if( $banner_image ){ ?>
                    <img  src="<?php echo $banner_image; ?>" alt="" class="slide-img" />

            </div>
            <?php }   
                endforeach;
              ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have tried the code but it doesn't seem to work for my website.

Comment: I have updated the code and used the code that you have provided me. It doesn't fetch images from Custom Post. I really don't know whats the issue with my website.

Comment: please visit http://alainc.msf.ae/ there should be background images in each of the section. This is a sandbox environment of my website.

Comment: Hi @Nik, I have copy pasted the code and all the sections have disappeared from the website. The header is there, but the custom posts are not there.

Comment: Your code is proper but just issue for not close <div> please verify starting and closing all tags and i just updated new code try this

Comment: I didn't notice that the <div> was misisng. Thank you for the support @Nik, but the sections and images are still not loading. Sections are there, the caption is disabled for the bannerslide0 and as there is no increment in the slides, the caption is not being displayed but thats okay. 
The images are still missing, I dont know what I am missing here.